# Reading whole files in Lua

Tags: io, lua

I am trying to read a full mp3 file in order to read out the id3 tags. That's when I noticed that file:read("*a") apparently does not read the full file but rather a small part. So I tried to build some kind of workaround in order to get the content of the whole file:

```
function readAll(file)
    local f = io.open(file, "r")
    local content = ""
    local length = 0

    while f:read(0) ~= "" do
        local current = f:read("*all")

        print(#current, length)
        length = length + #current

        content = content .. current
    end

    return content
end
```

for my testfile, this shows that 256 reading operations are performed, reading a total of ~113kB (the whole file is ~7MB). Though this should be enough to read most id3 tags, I wonder why Lua behaves in this way (especially because it does not when reading large textbased files such as *.obj or *.ase). Is there any explanation for this behaviour or maybe a solution to reliably read the whole file?

Comment: Are you on windows? make sure you open the file in binary mode ("rb" to io.open)

Comment: Argh, that was the point. Never had to use binary mode before. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Could someone explain the format ***all** in function `f:read("*all")` ?  It seems "*all" is equal to "*a" ? I could not find the document in lua manual https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-file:read

Comment: @liuhao All characters after the first two (The `*a`) are ignored, according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277203/what-is-the-all-format-in-lua-fileread-means
I guess I got this from this chapter in pil back in the days: https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html, the advantage being (I guess) that you don't have to remember what `*a`, `*n` and `*l` stand for, because you can instead write it out.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I must be missing something but I fail to see why a loop is needed. This should work (but you'd better add error handling in case the file cannot be opened):

```
function readAll(file)
    local f = assert(io.open(file, "rb"))
    local content = f:read("*all")
    f:close()
    return content
end
```

Comment: as can be seen in the comments to my question, @daurnimator already figured out that the problem was the missing b, but thanks for your answer anyway :) 
edit: I marked your answer as accepted in order to show people my question has been solved.

Comment: Hello. I arrived here by googling "lua read whole file". This answer could be improved: 1. demystify the `f:read("*all")` syntax - [at a minimum a link to What is the "*all* format in lua file:read() means?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47278239/14516046) would be nice. 2. Maybe mention [To-be-closed Variables](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.8), but warn that they are only available since lua 5.4