# Lua one-liner to read entire file?

Tags: lua, slurp

Is there a trick to slurp a file with just one line of code?

("to slup" = to read entire file into a string.)

Usually I do the following:

```
local f = io.open("/path/to/file")
local s = f:read("*a")
f:close()
```

But I wonder if there's a shorter way.

I know that we can do (in Lua 5.2) the following:

```
local s = io.lines("/path/to/file", "*a")()
```

But the file would stay open for a while until the garbage collector kicks in (and gets rid of the closure `io.lines` returns; I believe this closure knows to explicitly close the file, but this could happen only after the *second* invocation of it, when it knows EOF has been reached).

So, is there a one-line solution I'm missing?

Comment: Why do you need a one-liner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386672/reading-whole-files-in-lua.

Comment: @lhf: I need a one-liner because the code is to appear in an article. Since I need to "waste" 5 extra lines on this task (there are also 2 empty lines around), or 9 lines with catwell's solution, it means that I'll have to split my code into two functions and my code will no longer be succinct :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function in the standard library, but you can just define it yourself:

```
local function slurp(path)
    local f = io.open(path)
    local s = f:read("*a")
    f:close()
    return s
end
```

Alternatively there is such a function in [Penlight](https://lunarmodules.github.io/Penlight/libraries/pl.file.html#read).

Comment: Some error handling is need. The lazy way is to write `f = assert(io.open(path))`.

Comment: Well, if f is nil then `f:read()` will raise an error anyway... But sure, there should be error handling. The Penlight version does it: https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/blob/master/lua/pl/utils.lua#L117-L130

Answer (score 1):

So close() is not really needed you can 'Classic Online' it to...

```
local s = io.open("/path/to/file"):read("*a")
```

But in Lua you can always do Onliner in this way...

```
local f = io.open("/path/to/file") local s = f:read("*a") f:close()
```