# Load bytecode with load function

Tags: lua, bytecode

I used the `luac52.exe -o test.txt test.lua` command to made a bytecode of a `test.lua` file, named `test.txt`. Now, if I open the `test.txt` file with Notepad++, it contains some really strange black symbols. Now, how do I load it with the `load("abcde", nil, "bt", _ENV)()` command? I need to use the load function specificaly... Should I give a .txt extension?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the [load](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load) function?

Comment: How do  you intend on getting the contents of test.txt to the load function? And, .txt is a strange extension for a file that doesn't contain text. Some people use .lub for Lua Bytecode.

Comment: I don't know how to copy and paste the contents of .txt into "abcde" text of the load function as, indeed, it isn't a regular text... Even if I use .lub and open it with Notepad++ it has the exact same contents as the .txt though...

Comment: I suspect this question has the [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676). The best way to help you is for you to describe what your higher-level goal is and why you are constrained to using `load`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `loadfile("test.txt")` instead of `load`. This will give you a function that you need to run to execute whatever is in `test.txt`.

Or you can use `dofile("test.txt")`, which you load and run.

If you really need to use `load`, then read the contents of `test.txt` into a string and send it to `load`.

To read the contents of a file, see [Read whole file and print in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29647412/107090).

Comment: But I need to use the load function specifically as I mention T_T Is there any way it can be done with load?

Comment: First, thanks for the answers. I used c = f:read("*all") and if I test printing c then only a "LuaR" is printed. Even so, If I use load(c, nil, "bt", _ENV)() then it gives the error attempt to call a nil value...

Comment: `load` expects a function that returns the string or chunk to load. Try `load(function() return f:read "*a" end)`

Comment: Same, I used load(function() return f:read "*a" end, nil, "bt", _ENV)()